# stats find some probabilites $X =Norm(-4,25)$ by hand

Tags: statistics

Let $X =     Norm(-4,25)$ Find the following probabilites  without software

a) $P(X > 6)$

b) $P(-9 <X <1)$

c) $P(\sqrt{x}>1)$

---

the answers are (a) About 0.025; (b) 68%; (c) 0.16.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a table?

Comment: For the quiz.I Don't think so.  can have a calculator.  Where you going to use Z values?? some approximation? But I want to see how

Comment: the point here is that the value of $\Phi(2), \Phi(1)$ are somewhat common sense to remember

Comment: @Ugo Calculator, table ... What you are allowed to use? Your comment confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are supposed to use the Empirical Rule. It is based on
the normal distribution and thus applies (almost) exactly to the normal distribution.

The rule says that (i) the probability within one standard deviation $\sigma$ of the mean $\mu$ is about 68%, (ii) the probability within $\mu \pm 2\sigma$ is 
about 95%, (iii) the probability within $\mu \pm 3\sigma$ is 'about' 99.7% or
'almost all'.

Thus (a): 
$$P(X > 6) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{6-(-4)}{5}\right) = P(Z > 2).$$
Part (ii) says $P(-2 < Z < 2) \approx .95,$ where $Z$ has mean $0$ and standard deviation $1.$

Then by symmetry, there must
be about 2.5% of the probability in each tail $P(Z < -2) = P(Z > 2) \approx .025.$

Similarly, for (b): $P(-9 < X < 1) = P(-1 < Z < 1) \approx 0.68.$
And I'll leave (c) to you (after you change $x$ to $X$.)

In the figure below, from left to right, areas separated by vertical
dashed lines are about .025, .135, .34, .34, .135, and .025.

[image]